# How to properly use proxies in Python requests?

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

I have a list of proxies.
When I test one of them using `curl`:

```
curl -proxy https://x.x.x:port https://www.google.com/
```

I get the expected result, but when I run:

```py
proxies = {'http' : 'x.x.x:port', 'https' : 'x.x.x:port'}
requests.get('https://www.google.com/', proxies = proxies)
```

It is stuck for a while and then I get this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')))
```

I tried different ways of proxy definition, like:

```
'http' : 'http://x.x.x:port', 'https' : 'https://x.x.x:port'
```

and nothing works, always get this error, how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Just saw your last note of trying different ways which aligns with my first suggestion. You may want to try setting the proxy with the `os` library in my later suggestion.

There's two things that stand out to me:

1. You used `https://x.x.x:port` in your curl command but used
   `x.x.x:port` in Python. You might have to include `https://`.
2. You used both http and https. I don't think this one would cause an error, but still worth investigating

First, I would suggest including `https://` like so:

```
proxies = {'https' : 'https://x.x.x:port'}  
requests.get('https://www.google.com/', proxies = proxies)
```

Second, I would try just setting https (and if that fails, try just setting http):

```
import requests

proxies = {
  'https': 'https://x.x.x.x:port',
}

requests.get('https://example.org', proxies=proxies)
```

Also, you can set environmental proxies through Python like:

```
import os
os.environ["http_proxy"] = "http://x.x.x.x:port"
os.environ["https_proxy"] = "https://x.x.x.x:port"
```

or through the command line / command prompt

Windows

```
set http_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:port
set https_proxy=https://x.x.x.x:port
```

Linux/OS X:

```
export http_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:port
export https_proxy=https://x.x.x.x:port
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried setting enviromental proxies, but still getting the same error. Looks like something's wrong with requests, curl works perfect. Also I tried setting only https, both http and https, included and excluded schemas from url, still nothing.